# Proper positioning of `\underbrace`

Tags: align, underbrace

I'm trying to digitize my professor's lecture notes. How do I typeset the following equation?

[image: scanned-version]

This is what I've got so far:

```
\begin{align}
    & \sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l^\prime } \hat{q}_n (t) = \nonumber \\
    &= \sum_l \left\lbrace \hat{a}_l (t) \underbrace{ \sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l^\prime } u_{ n, l } }_{\delta_{ l l^\prime } } + \hat{a}^\dagger_l (t) \underbrace{ \sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l^\prime } u^*_{ n, l } }_{ \delta_{ l, -l^\prime } } \right\rbrace \nonumber \\
    &= \hat{a}_{l^\prime} (t) + \hat{a}^\dagger_{-l^\prime} (t) % Equation 3
\end{align}
```

which gives me the following output:
[image: latex-output]

As you can see, the `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`s are way too big. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `\biggl\lbrace` and `\biggr\rbrace` instead of `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you add it as an answer, so I can vote for it then close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of `\left` and `\right`.

You did a good job, but there are a couple of tricks to remember:

1. instead of `^\prime` it's easier to use `'`;
2. add braces around the whole `\underbrace{...}_{...}`.

You can see the correct placement of the plus sign in my output, which is incorrect in yours.

Also `equation` and `split` is better than `align`. If you remove the `tbtags` option, the equation number will be in the vertical middle, which in my opinion is preferable.

```latex
\documentclass[tbtags]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l' } \hat{q}_n (t) \\
&\quad = \sum_l \biggl\lbrace
  \hat{a}_l (t)
  {\underbrace{ \sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l' } u_{ n, l } }_{\delta_{ l l' } }}
  +
  \hat{a}^\dagger_l (t)
  {\underbrace{ \sum_{ n = 1 }^N u^*_{ n, l' } u^*_{ n, l } }_{ \delta_{ l, -l' } }}
\biggr\rbrace \\
&\quad = \hat{a}_{l'} (t) + \hat{a}^\dagger_{-l'} (t) % Equation 3
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `'`!

Comment: @wyphan And `f''` is MUCH simpler than `f^{\prime\prime}`

Comment: Why are braces around `\underbrace` important?

Comment: I think it groups the `\underbrace` as a single unit, such that the spacing around the plus sign becomes correct.